# INNER JOIN same value, but the difference is the other table are having extra word in front of the value

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

As I said in the title, or maybe my question is a little bit confusing. Here it is....

So, I want to combine 2 tables using INNER JOIN (ofcourse) with some difference.
This is my tables
Table 1, PK = steam_id

```
SELECT * FROM nmrihstats ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 4;
+---------------------+----------------+--------+-------+--------+
| steam_id            | name           | points | kills | deaths |
+---------------------+----------------+--------+-------+--------+
| STEAM_0:1:88467338  | Alan14         |  50974 |  5438 |     12 |
| STEAM_0:0:95189481  | ? BlacKEaTeR ? |  35085 | 24047 |    316 |
| STEAM_0:1:79891668  | Lowell         |  34410 | 44076 |    993 |
| STEAM_0:1:170948255 | Rain           |  29780 | 30167 |    278 |
+---------------------+----------------+--------+-------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Table 2, PK = authid

```
SELECT * FROM store_players ORDER BY credits DESC LIMIT 4;
+-----+-------------+---------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| id  | authid      | name          | credits | date_of_join | date_of_last_join |
+-----+-------------+---------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| 309 | 1:88467338  | Alan14        |   15543 |   1475580801 |        1482260232 |
| 368 | 1:79891668  | Lowell        |   10855 |   1475603908 |        1482253619 |
| 256 | 1:128211488 | Fuck[U]seLF   |   10422 |   1475570061 |        1482316480 |
| 428 | 1:74910707  | Mightybastard |    7137 |   1475672897 |        1482209608 |
+-----+-------------+---------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, how can I use INNER JOIN without doing like removing "STEAM_0:" or adding it. Also with explanation, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `join` witn `like` operator, e.g.:

```
SELECT n.*, sp.*
FROM nmrihstats n JOIN store_players sp ON n.steam_id LIKE CONCAT('%', sp.authid);
```

Here's the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b110e/2/0).

Another approach would be to use `String` functions of `MySQL` to extract out relevant part from `steam_id` but I believe that's not what you want:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(steam_id, LOCATE('STEAM_0:', steam_id) + CHAR_LENGTH('STEAM_0:'))
FROM nmrihstats;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful. Although it's a little bit slow if I have so many rows in the table, but since It's for individual purpose, still acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible, you need to remove "STEAM_0:", matching with WHERE, using substring for remove STEAM_0: from column equals to column in other table, or a new field into the T1 without "STEAM_0:", that 2 columns match for INNER JOIN

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Since the table is generated by 2 different CS:GO plugin, I will leave it like that. I understand a little bit about sourcemod, but the problem is, I cant find the creator of that plugin so I cant edit since I dont have the source file